# I have to create a dataframe from webscraping in a specific way

Tags: python, html, list, dataframe, beautifulsoup

I have to create a dataframe in python by creating a bunch of lists from a table in a wikipedia article.

code:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texas_Killing_Fields"
page = urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

all_tables = soup.find_all('table')
all_sortable_tables = soup.find_all('table', class_='wikitable sortable')
right_table = all_sortable_tables


A = []
B = []
C = []
D = []
E = []
for row in right_table.find_all('tr'):
    cells = row.find_all('td')
    if len(cells) == 5:
        row.strip('\n')
        A.append(cells[0].find(text=True))
        B.append(cells[1].find(text=True))
        C.append(cells[2].find(text=True))
        D.append(cells[3].find(text=True))
        E.append(cells[4].find(text=True))

df = pd.DataFrame(A, columns=['Victim'])
df['Victim'] = A
df['Age'] = B
df['Residence'] = C
df['Last Seen'] = D
df['Discovered'] = E
```

I keep getting an attribute error "ResultSet object has no attribute 'find_all'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?"

I have tried a bunch of methods and nothing has helped me. I'm also following a tutorial the teacher gave us and its not helpful either.

tutorial: https://alanhylands.com/how-to-web-scrape-wikipedia-python-urllib-beautiful-soup-pandas/#heading-10.-loop-through-the-rows

first time here btw as a questioner.

Comment: Please include the full traceback error.

Comment: Wikipedia has an API (Mediawiki), I'd just use  that. The error seems self-explanatory: `right_table.find_all('tr')` calls `.find_all` on a result set iterable when it needs to be called on a single element, say, `right_table[0]`, each `right_table`, or whatever makes sense for your implementation.

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** *As mentioned by @ggorlen using an existig api would be the best approache. I also would recommend to use a more structured approache to store your data to avoid these bunch of lists.*

```
data = []

for row in soup.select('table.wikitable.sortable tr:has(td)'):
    
    data.append(
        dict(
            zip([h.text.strip() for h in soup.select('table.wikitable.sortable tr th')[:5]],
                [c.text.strip() for c in row.select('td')][:5])
        )
    )

pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Just an alternative approach to scrape tables using [`pandas.read_html()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html) cause you already imported `pandas`. It also uses `BeautifulSoup` and is doing the job for you:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_html('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texas_Killing_Fields')[1]

df.iloc[:,:5] ### displays only the first 5 columns as in your example
```

Output:

| Victim | Age | Residence | Last seen | Discovered |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Brenda Jones | 14 | Galveston, Texas | July 1, 1971 | July 2, 1971 |
| Colette Wilson | 13 | Alvin, Texas | June 17, 1971 | November 26, 1971 |
| Rhonda Johnson | 14 | Webster, Texas | August 4, 1971 | January 3, 1972 |
| Sharon Shaw | 13 | Webster, Texas | August 4, 1971 | January 3, 1972 |
| Gloria Gonzales | 19 | Houston, Texas | October 28, 1971 | November 23, 1971 |

...